# How can I set root device EBS volume of EMR cluster using Cloud Formation Script

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, emr

I want to launch an AWS EMR cluster using AWS Cloud Formation Script. I am not able to set Root device EBS volume size. By default it creates a volume of size 10 GB. I want my cluster should have 50 GB Root Device EBS volume.

Comment: Agree this would be nice. The documentation shows how to do it with aws-cli or through the console, but not with cloudformation.

Comment: It appears that CF doesn't support this yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can specify the parameter EbsRootVolumeSize in your EMR cloudformation:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-emr-cluster.html#cfn-elasticmapreduce-cluster-ebsrootvolumesize

Comment: Thanks for reply. This is new update in CLoudFormation EMR setup.